# Problem related to IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

I am getting the continuous error of IndexOutOfRangeException in my c# code. The code snippet is follows:

```
public void GetAccountSalesDataTestWithAccountsIncluded()
{
    AccountSalesDataRepository target = new AccountSalesDataRepository();
    AccountSalesDataSearchCriteria[] searchCriteria = new AccountSalesDataSearchCriteria[2]
     {   
        new AccountSalesDataSearchCriteria
        {
             ProgramAccountId = new AccountSalesDataSearchCriteria.SearchCriteria<int>[1] { new AccountSalesDataSearchCriteria.SearchCriteria<int>(98, true) }
        },
        new AccountSalesDataSearchCriteria()
     };

    AccountSalesDataSummary[] results;
    results = target.GetAggregateAccountSalesData(searchCriteria, true);
    try
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(results, "The result set should not be null with the given account");
        Assert.IsTrue(results.Length > 0, "The result set should not be empty with given account");
    }
    catch (AssertFailedException /*ex*/)
    {
    }
    this.AccountSalesDataSummaryBasicTest(results, true);
    try
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(results[0].AccountId, 2);
        Assert.AreEqual(results[0].TotalPurchaseAmount, decimal.Parse("200"), "The total purchase amount is incorrect");
        Assert.AreEqual(results[0].TotalPurchaseQuantity, 2000, "The total purchase quantity is incorrect");
        Assert.AreEqual(results[0].TotalSaleQuantity, double.Parse("200"), "The total sales quantity is incorrect");
        Assert.AreEqual(results[0].TotalSalesAmount, decimal.Parse("20"), "The total sales amount is incorrect");
    }
    catch (AssertFailedException /*ex*/)
    {
    }
}
```

What can be the probable reason of this?

Please pardon me if I may give the idea that I am not coherent with my concepts, because I'm really new to this entire thing.

Comment: In which line the exception is throwing.

Comment: Assert.AreEqual(results[0].AccountId, 2);
All the assert.areequal statements are giving the same error.

Comment: How about starting with a `Assert.IsTrue(results.Count > 0)` ?

Comment: Actually my result set is empty. The `target.GetAggregateAccountSalesData(searchCriteria, true)` is returning empty set.

Comment: I'm closing this as too localised. Your problem arises (as you have commented above) because a method which we have no visibility of is returning no data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are apparently writing unit tests. The `AssertFailedException` indicates that one of your assertions has failed, and it should *not* be caught, because the entire point is that if an assertion fails, your entire test is supposed to fail (there is no point in continuing the test, because you already know that something is wrong). Furthermore, when you catch an exception and don't do anything in the `catch` block, you're effectively saying "if an exception is thrown, just ignore it and proceed". Thus, the assert that is supposed to check that the array actually contains something did its job, but you silenced it and made the test proceed even though the array is empty - hence the `IndexOutOfRangeException` in the next `try` block.

Remove the `try`/`catch` blocks (keeping the content of the `try` blocks), and you will see your test fail and tell you exactly what's wrong: the array is empty. The reason it is empty is either that there is a bug in `GetAggregateAccountSalesData()` (excellent, the test helped you find a bug), or that you have called it incorrectly, or that test data is missing (does there exist account sales data that can be aggregated?), or that something is somehow not set up properly (do you need to call some other methods in order for `GetAggregateAccountSalesData()` to work?) Try debugging the test and see what happens inside that method.

Comment: @user837610: Glad to hear it. If you are satisfied with the answer, you should mark it as "accepted" to indicate that other people do not need to spend time on your question.